# Do Code First Migrations Override the entire schema of an existing database?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have two remote database connections to existing MySQL databases, they already have tables and data in them. One of them is for testing purposes but it does have a lot of data in it.

I want to keep them in sync with Visual Studio and my models, but I need to be sure that it is safe to run the migrations and it will not override the existing schema.

Will the migrations just add and remove tables when they are run up and down, or will they mess with the existing data?

Comment: they can mess with the existing data. If you have a foreign key constraint, and your migration in some way is changing it, it will affect that data.

Comment: Why don't you look at the actual migrations and see what the commands say they're going to do?

Comment: There are currently no relationships between the tables in the test database, that is the problem it is taking forever to configure the database manually.